# serial execution of http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code in which i am trying to execute httpt request serially
Following is code

```
var httpPostData = function (postparameters,postData){

  return $http ({           
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : URL,
    params  : postparameters,
    headers: headers,
    data    : postData
   }).success (function (responseData){
         return responseData.data;
   })
}

for (var app of appArray){        

    var addAppPromise = httpPostData (restartAppParams,app);         
     addAppPromise.then(function(status){             
         console.log(status.data);             
     })
}
```

***appArray*** is list of servers where i am connecting one by one and doing some stuff as per parameter i am passing (restartAppParams) by above http post.

I want this execution to happen serially i.e. next http request should be executed only if previous one is finished and response has received.
Any idea how to do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to achieve this:

```
.controller('Samplecontroller', function($http, $q) {

   var restartAppParams = {}; 

   var httpPostData = function(postparameters, postData){

    return $http ({           
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : URL,
      params  : postparameters,
      headers: headers,
      data    : postData
     });

   };

   appArray.reduce(function(promise, app) {
      return promise.finally(function() {
        return httpPostData(restartAppParams, app)
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
          });
      })
   }, $q.when());

});
```

Comment: This approach has the added benefit of `appArray.reduce` returning a promise you can chain off. You should push the results to an array and return that rather than `console.log`ing, probably.

Comment: That really depends on what the user requires. I usually do this when accessing different end points, thus, different post processing for each response. So I guess accumulation of response data is **probably** not ideal, **probably**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var httpPostData = function(postparameters, postData, next) {

  return $http ({           
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : URL,
    params  : postparameters,
    headers : headers,
    data    : postData
   }).success (function (responseData) {
         if (typeof next == 'function') {
             next();
         }
   });
}

var appArrayCopy = appArray.slice();
function fetch() {
    if (appArrayCopy.length) {
        var app = appArrayCopy.shift();
        httpPostData(restartAppParams, app, fetch);
    } else {
        // finished
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not behave correctly if any of the requests fails and does not give you a way to error handle. You have a `typeof` check after `return` and you're not doing anything with the data.

Comment: @Nomad `shift` remove one element from the front of the array.

Comment: @jcubic yeh i know about shift, but i had array of 3 and after first execution nothing happened, each execution takes approximately 15 seconds to finish

Comment: @Nomad did you remove return from success callback?

Answer (score 0):

angularjs uses asynchronous ajax calls by default. It's actually hardcoded and can't be changed (see line 77 in [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/106f90aafa0fa5a81ad7af7ffc9d1e00ab97ffef/src/ng/httpBackend.js), which is HEAD of master branch at the time, I'm writing this).

Also, keep in mind that synchronous calls block everything else which is basically against the non-blocking approach javascript was built for.

If your app is dependant on the requests beeing done one after another, you could chain them using the promise and a recursive call.
Something like this should work:

```
function runXhr(app) {
  var addAppPromise = httpPostData (restartAppParams,app);   
  addAppPromise.then(function(status){             
    console.log(status.data);

    // calls the next service if appArray has any services left
    var app = appArray.shift();
    if (app) {
      runXhr(appArray.shift());
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  });
}
```